# Pinout on legacy audio jack

Tags: audio, repair, reverse-engineering, socket

The headphone jack on my old (= 20th century) Daewoo TV 20A5 is broken -- the tip of a plug is stuck inside. As the TV itself is working fine, I would like to replace the jack, or rather jerry-rig a new headphone jack to the existing contacts .... but which of the seven contacts should I use?

[image: daewoo pcb]

1 and 5 seem to be unconnected, this still leaves five options: left, right, ground, and a switch(?), but which is which?

**update:** the service manual contains the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

are 1, 5 and 8 the three contacts (ring, sleeve, tip) that i want?

Comment: How can you tell that they aren't connected? In some cases connectors may have legs that are just there for mechanical strain relief - in which case those pads may or may not be grounded. Also what is the tear near D603, is there a damage to the PCB there or just dirt? In general I wouldn't expect this board to work with this much dust and no PCB coating. If possible blow it away carefully using compressed air. Alternatively clean the whole thing up with isopropyl, but that's much more work. And perhaps needless to say, be aware of ESD like always.

Comment: Is there a type number on the top of the jack socket? With a jack plug with known connections and the continuity tester on a multimeter you should be able to figure out left, right, and ground, and measuring the other pins with and without the plug inserted should show what is switched by which pins. Worth a try, see how far you get.

Comment: the board is old and dirty, but the TV is working fine. just the headphone jack is broken / jammed. this means i cannot plug anything in for testing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you download the service manual for your TV. For example, from [here](https://www.download-service-manuals.com/) is the relevant part of a schematic for a Daewoo DTQ-20D series TV:

[image]

This one contains a dual pole switch to disable the speakers when the headphone plug is inserted. If the TV has only a mono speaker then some (a couple) of the connections may be unused.

Comment: cool, thanks for the link. i successfully downloaded the service manual for my Daewoo 20A5. the schematic for the headphone jack ("YSC1537") looks pretty similar to your example. this still doesn't tell me which pin is which, right?

Comment: It might be more of a help if it actually matched the PCB. However if it's moderately correct it tells you the function required (isolated switch) and maybe it's mono as shown (L & R pins 2 & 3 connected together) or not. The rest should be pretty easy to figure out with a plug and a multimeter.

Answer (score 1):

From the schematic, it's a mono TV, but wired so that it can work with stereo headphones.  6 doesn't appear to do anything.  7 and 8 aren't used.  4 and 5 are a switch to allow the sound through to the internal speaker if you haven't plugged anything in.  2 and 3 are the tip and ring of the headphone plug, and 1 is the sleeve.

If you want the TV to work normally, try to find another jack that also has switching contacts, so it can turn the speaker on and off.  They should still be available.  You will need all the pins except 6, 7 and 8 wired to the new jack.

Comment: awesome, simon! so i want (at least) pins 1, 2, 3 to get a headphone signal. i assume those are the numbers from the schematic? unfortunately, the contacts on the PCB are not labelled, the yellow numbers are my own. so what's your best guess which pins are tip, ring and sleeve?

i think i'll try yellow 2, 3, 4 first.

Comment: @tlossen It's not al all obvious.  The best was might be to examine the existing socket, and also "buzz it out" with a multimeter on the continuity range.  But if there's a broken plug, that may be difficult.